# Convergence in Distribution to Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $(X_n)$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, $E[X_1]=\mu$ and $Var[X_1]=\sigma^2$, $\overline{X_n}=\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}X_i$, $S^2_n=\frac{1}{n-1}\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\overline{X_n})^2$

I want to show $\sqrt{n}(S^2_n-\mu^2)\xrightarrow {d}N(0,\mu_4-\sigma^4)$ where $\mu_4$ is the centered fourth moment of $X_1$

There are two steps to the problem, first show $S^2_n\xrightarrow {d}\sigma^2$, then show $\sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\mu)^2-\sigma^2)\xrightarrow {d}N(0,\mu_4-\sigma^4)$

I was able to do the first step showing $S^2_n\xrightarrow {d}\sigma^2$, but I am stuck on the proving $\sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\mu)^2-\sigma^2)\xrightarrow {d}N(0,\mu_4-\sigma^4)$. How can I do the second part and use it to prove the result $\sqrt{n}(S^2_n-\mu^2)\xrightarrow {d}N(0,\mu_4-\sigma^4)$?

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, try to use Central Limit Theorem for
$$
    \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i
$$
where $Y_i = (X_i - \mu)^2$ and for the last part, notice that
$$
     Y_i = (X_i - \bar{X}_n)^2 + 2(X_i - \bar{X}_n)(\bar{X}_n - \mu) + (\bar{X}_n - \mu)^2
$$
then,
$$
    \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \bar{X}_n)^2 + (\bar{X}_n - \mu)^2
$$
By the Law of Large Numbers, you can show that
$$
    (\bar{X}_n - \mu)^2 \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} 0
$$
Then, the result is proven